# Set "azureML.CLI Compatibility Mode" in Visual Studio Code

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service

In [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-debug-visual-studio-code) tutorial, it is asked to set the `azureML.CLI Compatibility Mode` setting to 1.0 for the Azure Machine Learning extension. However, when checking the settings of the extension, such option is not available.

Comment: Can you please give information about the location where you got blocked while doing these steps? Whether while creating experiment of any other location.

Comment: Can't find the option to set it to 1.0

Comment: @TadepalliSairam In step 4, there is no "Create experiment" option when I right click on the "Experiments" node. The "Experiments" node does not open. It keeps endlessly refreshing.

Answer (score 1):

Install version 0.6.28 of Azure Machine Learning extension. It looks this is the last one that supports AzureML CLI 1.0.

[image: here the screenshot]

Then there is available option in settings to set to CLI 1.0

Answer (score -1):

These are the steps to be followed to check and update the Azure ML.CLI compatibility mode version

1. Open Visual Studio. If not installed. Check the [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) to download the software.
2. Go to **FILE** menu and click on Pre**strong text**ferences then on **Extensions** as mentioned in the image

[image]

3. In the search bar, search for **Azure Machine Learning.**

[image]

Choose the first option and click on **INSTALL**. As I already installed, it will show **UNINSTALL** for me

4. Go to **File->Preferences->Settings**

[image]

[image]

Click on **Extensions->Azure Machine Learning -> Under Azure CLI Tools configuration** and scroll down.

[image]

Under **Azure ML >YAML:Schemas**
Click on **Edit in settings.json**

[image]

**We can find the** **azureML.CLI version as 1.0** (this is from my side). Check this on your version and change it here.

Comment: The option is not there for me! I added it manually, but, it didn't resolve my original issue with remote debugging. I wonder if it has something to do with my WSL setup

Comment: Once try to reinstall VSCode and check the same procedure. If the same repeats. Then WSL would be the alternative process.

Comment: I'll try the reinstall. But, my main issue is: I can't load azure experiments from VSCode

Comment: If possible can you please brief the type of azure experiment you are trying to load from VSCode.

Comment: Machine Learning experiments. When I click on "experiment" under my workspace, it keeps on loading and never shows anything.